# C++ templated class default constructor fails

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

So I am creating a Stack class for an assignment in C++. The core of the assignment is to familiarize us with templates. I have read my book over and over and looked question after question on here.

I need to have my Stack class be able to be constructed by

```
Stack s2;
```

but I get an error when I compile my test.cpp and can only compile when i construct as

```
Stack<T> s1;
```

where `T` is a `std::string`, `int`, etc. How do build my Stack so I can use both constructors?

---

Stack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
class Stack {
public:
    Stack();
    void Push(T val);
    T Pop();
    void Print();

private:
    vector<T> vecT;
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack() { }

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::Push(T val) { vecT.push_back(val); }

template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::Pop() { vecT.pop_back(); }

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::Print() {
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int i=0; i<vecT.size(); i++) {
        cout << vecT[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]";
}
```

---

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#include "Stack.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Stack<string> s1;
        s1.Push("values1");
        s1.Push("values2");
        s1.Print();

    Stack s2;
        s2.Push("values1");
        s2.Push("values2");
        s2.Print();
}
```

Comment: [*Never, under no circumstances, and without exceptions, should you ever `using namespace std;` at global scope.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721)

Answer (score 1):

What about a default template parameter?

```
template<typename T = std::string> 
class Stack {
```

Anyway, with

```
Stack<T> s1;
```

and

```
Stack s2;
```

you're not using different constructors; you're using, in both cases, the same default (no arguments) constructor.

Comment: This will become `Stack<> s2;`. `Stack s2` won't compile unless you have C++1z

Answer (score 0):

Instead of templating everything you could just use a stack of a variant type (since C++17, before use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html)).  With the code below you can now push `int`, `double`, and `std::string` onto the stack.  Furthermore, `Pop()` is missing a return statement.  Also, `pop_back()` of vector returns nothing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class Stack {
    using Variant = std::variant<int,double,std::string>;
public:
    Stack();
    void Push(Variant val);
    void Pop();
    void Print();

private:
    std::vector<Variant> vecT;
};

Stack::Stack() : vecT() {}

void Stack::Push(Variant val) { vecT.push_back(val); }

void Stack::Pop() { vecT.pop_back(); }

void Stack::Print() {
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for ( auto const& v : vecT )
        std::visit([] (auto&& arg) { std::cout << arg << " "; }, v);
    std::cout << "]\n";
}

int main() {
    Stack s1;
        s1.Push("values1");
        s1.Push("values2");
        s1.Print();

    Stack s2;
        s2.Push("values1");
        s2.Push("values2");
        s2.Print();
}
```

---

With [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html) you get a C++98 compatible solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class Stack {
    typedef boost::variant<int,double,std::string> Variant;
    typedef std::vector<Variant>::iterator Iterator;

    std::vector<Variant> vecT;

    struct visitor : public boost::static_visitor<void>
    {
        template < typename T >
        void operator()(T const& arg) const { std::cout << arg << " "; }
    };
public:
    Stack();
    void Push(Variant val);
    void Pop();
    void Print();
};

Stack::Stack() : vecT() {}

void Stack::Push(Variant val) { vecT.push_back(val); }

void Stack::Pop() { vecT.pop_back(); }

void Stack::Print() {
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for ( Iterator it = vecT.begin(); it != vecT.end(); ++it )
        boost::apply_visitor( visitor(), *it );
    std::cout << "]\n";
}

int main() {
    Stack s1;
        s1.Push("values1");
        s1.Push("values2");
        s1.Print();

    Stack s2;
        s2.Push("values1");
        s2.Push("values2");
        s2.Print();
}
```

Comment: This will not compile for me?

Comment: @Zhawn Did you enable C++17?

Comment: I don't think I have. I installed the normal g++ compiler for Linux mint about a month ago and left the normal settings?

Comment: @Zhawn The second part of the updated answer now contains a C++98 compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a default template parameter:

```
template<typename T = int> 
class Stack {
```

Then you could construct using:

```
Stack<> s2;
```

Also, the constructors are identical, you aren't calling a different one each time, but rather the template argument differs.